# Why did the 747-8's freighter version make its first flight before the passenger version?

Tags: commercial-aviation, boeing, boeing-747

I have read that the 747-8F entered service in October 2011, almost eight months ahead of the passenger version (747-8I).

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The launch customers for the 747-8 were [Cargolux](https://www.cargolux.com/Home) and [Nippon Cargo Airlines](https://www.nca.aero/e/index.html), both air freight operators who wanted the 747-8F. The first orders for the 747-8I didn't materialize until several months later.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747-8#747-8_Freighter)